# this-> или Class::?

Tags: c++

Возникла ситуация с конфликтом имени переменной функции и менем функции этого класса, отсюда и вопрос.
Вараинт 1:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()  {}
    ~Foo() {}

public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "member foo" << std::endl; }

    void bar (int foo)
    {
    //  foo(); // Error
        this->foo();
        Foo::foo();
    }
};
```

Вариант 2:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()  {}
    ~Foo() {}

public:
    static void foo() { std::cout << "static foo" << std::endl; }

    void bar (int foo)
    {
    //  foo(); // Error
        this->foo();
        Foo::foo();
    }
};
```

Вызов:

```
int main()
{
    Foo().bar(42);

    return 0;
}
```

В обоих вариантах будет дважды вызвана функция foo (обычная и статическая).
Можете рассказать в чем разница между обращением через this и через :: внутри класса?

Вопрос уже отвечен тут (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c), но непонятно, есть ли оличия поведения при вызове непосредственно внутри класса

Comment: зачем вы параметр называете так же, как и метод? Оттого и ошибка с вызовом `foo()`. Измените `void bar (int foo)` на `void bar (int a)`, и ошибка исчезнет.

Comment: В чем подразумевается разница между двумя вариантами? На что должна повлиять статичность вызываемой функции?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант `Foo::foo()` приведет к подавлению виртуальности, т.е. в ситуации, когда метод `foo()` является виртуальным, вызов получится невиртуальным. Вариант `this->foo()` виртуальность не подавляет.

То есть если задача состоит именно и только в том, чтобы обойти сокрытие имен, т.е. восстановить поведение исходного варианта `foo()`, не нарушая никакой другой функциональности вызова, то правильным является именно вариант `this->`.

Этот же способ сработает для полей и элементов перечислений. Для ссылки на имена вложенных типов придется применять `::`, ибо доступ через оператор `->` к ним невозможен.

Comment: Вы можете также указать случай, когда имя члена производного класса скрывает имя члена базового класса. Тогда используется квалифицированное имя для члена базового класса. А также можете указать использование using-объявления для конструктора базового класса.

Answer (score 2):

Обращение через this-> служит для вызова методов объекта, Class:: имеет 2 варианта, либо вызов статического метода, либо вызов определенного метода родительского класса.

Comment: Что значит "два варианта"? А если я, как в примере, вызываю определенный метод именно этого класса (не родительского), то это как вписывается в ваши "два варианта"? И зачем вызов статического метода вынесен в отдельный вариант?